# AngularJS: Mix data from two JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

For a web app, I'm loading data from two JSON files using AngularJS. I can output both of the files data in my HTML, but I have to find a way to use data from the first file (`posts.json`) to address the second (`users.json`).

Example for `posts.json`:

```
{
  "title": "Some topic",
  "thread_id": 111,
  "messages": [
    {
      "user_id": 123,
      "message": "Hello, I'm Jim"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 987,
      "message": "Hi Jim, I'm Bob"
    },
  ]
}
```

Example for `users.json`:

```
[
  {
    "123": {
      "name": "Jim",
      "location": "London",
      "website": "http://j.im"
    }
  },
  {
    "987": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "location": "New York",
      "website": "http://b.ob"
    }
  }
]
```

A simple HTML example could look like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="talk in talks.messages">{{talk.name}} says {{talk.message}}</p>
```

However, I'd also like to add some of the meta-data of a user within the `ng-repeat` block, for instance link the user-name to his website.

Or to put it in an ill-formed expression, something like this:

```
<a href="{{{{talk.user_id}}.website}}">{{talk.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a mapping object in your controller or directive. Something like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($scope, _) {
  $scope.posts = /* load your posts */
  $scope.users = /* load your users */
  $scope.usersById = _.indexBy($scope.users, 'id')
})
```

Then you would use it in your template like:

```
<p ng-repeat="talk in talks.messages">
  {{talk.title}} by {{usersById[talk.user_id].name}}
</p>
```

Comment: This works when I adjust my `users.json` (see [example](http://codepen.io/idleberg/pen/zxqLmm)), but using the structure given above it does. I wouldn't necessarily mind changing the structure, but I was hoping mine was faster as I only need to load the users that match a post. PS: You should probably have mentioned your solution requires underscore.js!